# sort of asked before but would be good to get updated sources of tick data

Tags: intraday

Hi: I am looking for reasonably priced quote data or ohlc minute bars for US stocks. I would want the history  to go back say 2 or 3 years.

I realize that getting US quote data for reasonable prices is probably hopeless but I'm not even clear on the best vendor for OHLC bars in the US.

quantquote doesn't respond to my queries and I've heard some negative things about pi trading but these negatives may not be true and could just be a product of trolling.  Thanks for any updates since this question was last asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it probably depends on how you define “reasonably priced”. Data from Bloomberg and Refinitiv are a little bit over expensive, but they are for sure options. As to quantquote, I doubt if they still stay in business. Check out this post, where people talked about their experience with quantquote.

For equity tick data, I have experience with three vendors:

TickData.com - US equities listed in NYSE, AMEX, NASDAQ and CTA participants starting from January 1993. Offers custom-built time series and a ticker mapping feature. It can be very expensive though.

Algoseek.com - for intraday historical data starting from 2007. Offers the most comprehensive customizable minute bars in the industry with 50+ fields.

Nanex.net - for intraday data from 2004. Covers all US equity data including NBBO and regional exchange quotes. Data is 90% compressed to save space and time. Their software is a bit complicated to use and outdated though.

Comment: I ended up going with algoseek and I'm happy with it. Thanks for your thorough reply.

Comment: I would second algoseek as well. They have transparent and quite reasonable pricing plus multiple numerous delivery options and data formats.